# Tag Synonyms autocorrect

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

For extremely similar tags, like [gambit] and [gambits] or [opening] and [openings], can we make it so that one tag immediately autocorrects into the original one?

Comment: This would need to be done on system level, it's not something we can change at Chess.SE. I think it has some merit (searching for 'gambit' will automatically include posts where the word 'gambits' is used) but I doubt it can be easily implemented.

Comment: So I should be asking about this on Meta Stack Exchange?

Comment: Yes, the entire network would benefit from this. But there might be situations where this is not desirable and I haven't thought about the impact (what if there is a situation where we *need* two tags where one is the plural version of the other?). Also, one-sentence feature requests posted there by new users might not be well-received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually already happens for many tags.  You can see the complete list here:
https://chess.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms

I created a synonym for [gambit](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gambit) to [gambits](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gambits) (although there wasn't actually anything tagged with gambit).